# Is exporting third party library dependencies good programming practice?

Tags: scala, dependencies, singleton

I am using Intellij 14  and in the module settings, there is an option to export dependencies.

I noticed when I write objects that extend traits, I need to select **export**in the module settings when other modules try to use these objects.

For example,

```
object SomeObj extends FileIO
```

would require me to export the **FileIO** dependency.

However, if I write a companion class that creates a new instance when the object is called, the exporting is no longer necessary.

```
object SomeObject {
   private val someObject = new SomeObject()
   def apply() = someObject
}

private[objectPkg] class SomeObject() extends FileIO {}
```

This code is more verbose and kind of a hack to the singleton pattern for Scala.  Is it good to **export** third party dependencies with your module?  If not, is my pattern the typical solution with Scala?

Comment: It all depends on what you are doing and long term goals. Fully abstracting away all implementation details (eg some thirdparty library to access filesystem or db) may require more effort and not always necessary.

Comment: @dmitry i think agree with you. do you have a personal guideline of when it is not necessary?

Comment: It all deal with code design principles in general. Basically, if you may switch underlying third party library later, or you system must be flexible to be ported over some other libs - then hiding implementation behind some facade is a must. Often there is a ready-made set of interfaces in java/scala, which are implemented in third-party and you may just use those ones as a part of your facade to the rest of the system. If this is not the case - you will need to derive interfaces by yourself. The worthiness of this everyone estimates by oneself in context.

Comment: As per your case: keep in mind that in java/scala you export **names**, and if you will just use your class (which extends `FileIO`) in any way outside (your defining code), this means that class is accessible publicly and its type is exported/leaked outside as well. Scala should throw compile error, if some private class escapes its visibility scope, so, I'm not sure how you were going to utilise your `SomeObject.apply`. How?

Comment: This is just a general pattern I have been using for utilities packages.  I think I understand the gist of what you are saying.  Would you mind posting your answer below so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all deal with code design principles in general. Basically, if you may switch underlying third party library later, or you system must be flexible to be ported over some other libs - then hiding implementation behind some facade is a must.

Often there is a ready-made set of interfaces in java/scala, which are implemented in third-party and you may just use those ones as a part of your facade to the rest of the system, and overall it is a *java* way. If this is not the case - you will need to derive interfaces by yourself. The worthiness of this everyone estimates by oneself in context.

As per your case: keep in mind that in java/scala you export names, and if you will just use your class (which extends `FileIO`) in any way outside your defining code, this means that class is accessible publicly and its type is exported/leaked outside as well. Scala should throw compile error, if some private class escapes its visibility scope (so in your second version of `SomeObject` it may be the case).

Consider this example: I use typesafe config library often in my applications. It has convenient methods, but I typically leave the space for possible separation (or rather my own extension):

```
package object config {
  object Config {
    private val conf: TypeSafeConfig = ConfigFactory.load()

    def toTypeSafeConfig: TypeSafeConfig = conf
  }

  @inline implicit def confToTypeSafeConfig(conf: Config.type): TypeSafeConfig = conf.toTypeSafeConfig
}
```

Implicit conversion just allows me to call all `TypeSafeConfig` methods on my `Config`, and it has a bunch of convenient methods. Theoretically in future I could remove my implicit and implement methods I used right in the `Config` object. But I can hardly imagine why I would spend the time on this, though. This is some example of leaked implementation, that I don't consider problematic.